# What is Solution for error number16822 in autoupdating inAIR application using flash professional cs5.5

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I follow the https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CXKpw1HNoUA but its giving an error as

There was an error downloading the update. Error# 16822

Answer (score 0):

If your code is correct is possible it's an AIR issue.
Have you tried this? http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/help-application-doesnt-update.html

Comment: Thanks your Response. I would visit this " http://helpx.adobe.com/creative-suite/kb/help-application-doesnt-update.html" but i am not getting that type error. it is error while downloading an new version app.